# Dynamic Websites on Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to figure out how Dynamic Websites on Parse work.
I have followed the instructions here: https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#webapp to set up a basic example.

Beside cloud/views/hello.ejs, I have made cloud/views/mything.ejs and used that from app.js and it all works.

Now I would like to show for example the number of records in MyClass on Parse.
In other words, inside my Dynamic Website I want to display information related to the contents of the DB on Parse.
How can I do that? Obviously I need to include some DB query at some point, but is there any sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example snippet

This handles a GET request to /mypage, on execution it creates a [Parse Query](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries) but returns a [result count](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-counting) instead of a record set matching the query. On completion of the query we then set a count or error on the response using res.set(). You can then use ejs to display the count or error.

```
app.get('/mypage', function(req, res) {
      var query = new Parse.Query('My Class');
      query.equalTo("name", "Joe Blogs");
      query.count({
        success: function(count) {
          res.set('count', count);
        },
        error: function(error) {
          res.set('error', error);     
        }
      });
    });
```